# how to place different UIImages

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

Depending on the result of some user input, i have to show from 0 to n number of images [lines in a chart style background] in a 
view, changing on the x axis,

the problem is that i dont know before hand how many images are going to be needed to draw,

so i cannot create all the UIImageViews needed [nor is elegant coding]

here an example of what I mean

```
UIImageView *img = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 30, 12, 200)] autorelease];
[img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"line.png"]];
img.opaque = YES;
[self.view addSubview:img];
//[img release];


UIImageView *img2 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(102, 30, 12, 200)] autorelease];
[img2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"line.png"]];
img2.opaque = YES;
[self.view addSubview:img2];

UIImageView *img3 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(202, 30, 12, 200)] autorelease];
[img3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"line.png"]];
img3.opaque = YES;
[self.view addSubview:img3];


UIImageView *img4 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(302, 30, 12, 200)] autorelease];
[img4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"line.png"]];
img4.opaque = YES;
[self.view addSubview:img4];
```

so how to accomplish this?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If in `height` you have **height** of your view, than:

```
for (int x=2; x<height; x+=100)
{
    UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 30, 12, 200)];
    [img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"line.png"]];
    img.opaque = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:img];
    [img release];
}
```

Comment: You have set img to autorelease **AND** manually released it.